# Symfony search form - no result

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I am working on a project so that users can find music concerts based on a start date, an end date, an artist, and a city.

When I submit my search form,  it shows no result.
I hope you can help me solve both of these problems.

Ps: I have an event entity owner of the artist and city entities.

Controller

```
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Display formsearch and events on index Page
     *
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function search(Request $request)
{
    $events=[];
    $searchData = new searchData();

    $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $searchData);

    if ($request->isMethod('Post')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $events = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Event::class)->findDataByCriteria($searchData);
        }

    } else {
        $events = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Event::class)->findLastThreeMonths();
    }

    return $this->render('home/index.html.twig',
        ['form' => $form->createView(), 'events' => $events]);
}
}
```

Twig (template)

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig.' %}

{% block title %}Os Concerts{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{#<!-- Form search --> #}
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Concerts en France</h1>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="text-left">Rechercher un évènement</h3>
            {{ form_start(form) }}
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form_row(form.startDate) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form_row(form.endDate) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form_row(form.artist) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form_row(form.city) }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary align-bottom">Rechercher</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{#<!-- search result display or events for the next 3 months --> #}
<div class="container" mt-4>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="liste">
        <thead>
        <th scope="col">Où
        </td>
        <th scope="col">Quand
        </td>
        <th scope="col">Qui
        </td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for event in events %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ event.city.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.date|date }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.artist.name }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Repository

```
public function findDataByCriteria(SearchData $searchData)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

    $qb->select('e, a, c')
        ->leftJoin('e.artist', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('e.city', 'c');

    if (($searchData->getStartDate() != null && $searchData->getEndDate()) != null) {
        $qb->andWhere('e.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
            ->setParameter('startDate', $searchData->getStartDate())
            ->setParameter('endDate', $searchData->getEndDate());
    }

    if ($searchData->getCity() != null) {
        $qb->andWhere('c = :city')
            ->setParameter('city', $searchData->getCity());
    }

    if ($searchData->getArtist() != null) {
        $qb->andWhere('a.name LIKE :artist')
            ->setParameter('artist', '%' . $searchData->getArtist() . '%');
    }
    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    }
```

Entity SearchData

```
class SearchData
{

private $startDate;

private $endDate;

private $artist;

private $city;



public function getStartDate(): ?\DateTime
{
    return $this->startDate;
}


public function setStartDate(\DateTime $startDate = null): void
{
    $this->startDate = $startDate;
}


public function getEndDate(): ?\DateTime
{
    return $this->endDate;
}


public function setEndDate(\DateTime $endDate = null): void
{
    $this->endDate = $endDate;
}

public function getArtist(): ?string
{
    return $this->artist;
}


public function setArtist(string $artist): void
{
    $this->artist = $artist;
}


public function getCity(): ?string
{
    return $this->city;
}


public function setCity(string $city): void
{
    $this->city = $city;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
}
```

Formtype

```
class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('startDate', DateTimeType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'html5' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'from'],
        ])
        ->add('endDate', DateTimeType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'html5' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'to'],
        ])
        ->add('artist', TextType::class)
        ->add('city', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => City::class,
        ]);

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => SearchData::class,
        'csrf_protection' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'forms'
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to select only one "entity", for example by removing $qb->select('e, a, c') ?

Comment: I modified the repository to search between 2 dates, then a search for an artist between 2 dates. only the request for the city does not work

Comment: I solved my problem. The error is at the repository level : 
$qb->andWhere('c = :city')
$qb->andWhere('c.name = :city')